# Libgdx - How to change GestureListener pan finger sensibility?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, touch

I implemented GestureListener in my Overlap2dStage to pan the camera when the player drags its finger over the screen. But I also have some actors that extend InputAdapter to detect when the user touches on them. Then I mix them with a InputMultiplexer.

So far it's working fine on my computer, but when I get into Android and tap an object it trigers  both: `pan()` from stage and `touchDown()` from the actor.

I remember I read something about a pan box to decrease the sensibility, since in a touch screen you are touching several pixels, it detectes a pan. It's worst in smaller screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are looking for the constructor:

```
GestureDetector(float halfTapSquareSize, float tapCountInterval, 
        float longPressDuration, float maxFlingDelay, 
        GestureDetector.GestureListener listener)
```

The default constructor has this values: halfTapSquareSize=20, tapCountInterval=0.4f, longPressDuration=1.1f, maxFlingDelay=0.15f.

I don't know with which value you need to change to get what you are looking for. But you could play with them.

Another thing, you could return `false` for the `touchDown()` event, as [this site](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2013/10/24/LibGDX-Tutorial-5-Handling-Input-Touch-and-gestures.aspx) says:

> If you are supporting multi touch, be sure to return false from the more atomic events such as touchDown and TouchUp, so they still get a crack at handling those events.

Comment: Thanks I fixed it using:
gestureDetector.setTapSquareSize(Gdx.graphics.getDensity()*30)